# Emptying a List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, list

This has probably been asked somewhere, but I was unable to find it.

I have a List of strings like this :

```
public static List<string> AnimalsL = new List<string>();

public static void ListAnimals()
  {
    AnimalsL.Add("Animal one");
    AnimalsL.Add("Animal two");
   }

public static void ReturnAnimals()
{
    string[] Animals = AnimalsL.ToArray();
    if(AnimalsL != null)
    { 
        for(int Index = 0; Index < Animals.Length; Index++)
        { 
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Animals[Index].ToString()); 
        }
    }        
}
```

[b] Above is working code [/b]

So, as the title says, my real question is : How to completely empty a List of strings ?

For instance, I could want to store the animal names IF the animals type is snake, or dog, and I wouldn't want them crossing into the same category, or if I want to ensure the list is empty before adding to it, or clear it once I've used my methods on the animal.

I was thinking of declaring Animals[] = string.Empty, but this wouldn't actually clear the list ..

Comment: `AnimalsL.Clear();` ??

Comment: So simple, every related question was talking of the List<T> & I just don't know what the <T> means, thanks to everyone that has answered =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1.

```
AnimalsL.Clear(); // clears all the items in the list
```

2.

```
AnimalsL = new List<string>(); // assigns a new instance
```

Actually, creating a new instance is faster than calling the Clear method, though if you want to keep the reference to that object, then calling Clear is better.

Here is a benchmark for `Clear() vs new List` [Link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-clear)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`List<T>.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.110).aspx) method to remove all entries from a list instance.

Comment: And then be certain to bookmark this link so you know where to look for trivial answers like this.

Comment: I'd really like to understand this, but cannot find an explanation online. Why the <T> ? Thanks